RAID10: Help, how did I configure this thing? Data is there, but my knowledge is not
First off, I'm certainly a moron. I created a RAID 10 array a number of months ago and I hadn't rebooted my computer to ensure that it would startup properly. At this point, I don't even remember what tool I used to create it, but I'm pretty sure it was command line, possibly lvm. It used sda, sdb, sdc, and sdd drives. I have confirmed that I can read from each drive with the head command. I'm getting the error "not enough operational mirrors" with mdadm.
When I run lsblk it shows an md1 partition for sdc and sdd. Both sda and sdb have the exact same PTUUID when I run blkid and have PTTYPE="gpt". sdc and sdc have the same label, same UUID (but different from sda and sdb), different UUID_SUB labels and both have the TYPE="linux_raid_member". Also from lsblk, sda, sdb, sdc and sdd all report 10.9T, but the md1 partition on sdc and sdd along with a number of other block devices sde-sdk report 0B. Nothing is marked read only. Each drive is actually 3TB, not the 12 reported.
What I'm trying to do is figure out how to get everything to run as one logical device again like it was. I suspect that I just need to tell my computer how I previously configured this and put it in the right configuration file. My computer is booting in emergency mode and can't get past this because that RAID device, while not essential for booting, is essential for all the user accounts.
Help appreciated! This is my first question here since I'm more of a software person, so I apologize if I am not giving the right info. I can't easily get the printouts of running commands though because the computer with the issue is pretty broken until this gets fixed.
